# Is there a way to implement Vectorized UDFs in Spark?

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

In Pandas, you can do this:

```
@pandas_udf(df.schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def subtract_mean(pdf):
    return pdf.assign(v=pdf.v - pdf.v.mean())

df.groupby('id').apply(subtract_mean)
```

Is there a way we can do this in Spark? So basically, applying a custom function to a grouped by set?

Answer (score -1):

Seems like you need the [`pandas_udf`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.pandas_udf.html) decorator. If your Spark version is higher than 2.3 you can use it. There are some usage differences after Spark 3, so check that.

Given that you want to use it in a grouped DataFrame, a relevant example from the docs page is:

```py
@pandas_udf("double")
def mean_udf(v: pd.Series) -> float:
    return v.mean()

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1, 1.0), (1, 2.0), (2, 3.0), (2, 5.0), (2, 10.0)], ("id", "v"))

df.groupby("id").agg(mean_udf(df['v'])).show()

# Output:
# +---+-----------+
# | id|mean_udf(v)|
# +---+-----------+
# |  1|        1.5|
# |  2|        6.0|
# +---+-----------+
```

Comment: I understand this is a good solution if you can include pandas, but is there a way to do this through Spark only? Example, in Scala or Java?